# LUKS Unlock Linux (Fedora) with non-US Keyboard layout

Tags: linux, luks, system-recovery

If I boot normally (1 of 3 kernels), my keyboard layout is set to my physical layout (in my case CH-DE). There are 2 issues:

In case I have a system boot failure and I need to use the recovery mode,

1. Keyboard layout is set back to default, US (OK, no worries, with a bit of try and error I can figure out which keys to press)

**BUT**

2. In my case my password uses the character `#`, however, to issue `#` I have to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> (<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>). This however does not issue the `#` char but switches between GUI and Text mode.

Therefore I have no way to use the recovery mode.

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: DE-DE keyboard user here. Never heard of AltGr being equivalent to Ctrl+Alt. Also, on a US keyboard layout, `#` is mapped to "uppercase" 3, not to AltGr+3.